# Implicit doesn't work but thread sleep does

Tags: c#, selenium

My code with sleep works great but when I put to code implicit it doesn't.

Works

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(http://bit.ly);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='shorten_url']")).SendKeys("http://google.com");
Thread.Sleep(1500);
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='shorten_actions']")).Click();

outL.Text += driver.FindElement(By.XPath(//*[@id='shorten_actions']//input[@class='copy-input'])).GetAttribute("value") + "\r\n";
```

Doesn't work

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://bit.ly");
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='shorten_url']")).SendKeys("http://google.com");

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='shorten_actions']")).Click();

outL.Text += driver.FindElement(By.XPath(//*[@id='shorten_actions']//input[@class='copy-input'])).GetAttribute("value") + "\r\n";
```

Can someone explain me why?

Comment: becouse implicitwait is applied to every we element in your DOM. if it does not find at that particular at given intervel it will throw NoSuchelement error

Comment: So what i supposed to do

Comment: what type of driver is this and version?

Comment: 3.7 Chromedriver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using a different approach as opposed to relying on the driver's implicit wait:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(by));
```

You can wrap this up in a method

```
public static IWebElement FindElement(IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    if (timeoutInSeconds > 0)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds));
        return wait.Until(drv => drv.FindElement(by));
    }
    return driver.FindElement(by);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's better but not ideal. Is it possible to add to second code conditional for checking is it clickable